# Estimated work vs work done by user story in Team Foundation

Tags: tfs, reporting, sprint, agile-processes

We use the agile process of the Team Foundation Server.

I would like to get a report showing the orgininal estimated work vs the total work it really took for each user stories in our last sprints.

Is there an easy way I can get that or I would have to build a custom report ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a simple one-shot report, you can use Excel as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286627.aspx). Investing development effort to crank data through Reporting services, is useful if you reuse the report many times, say a standardized report sent every monday to all teams.